# Создание словаря суммированием списка

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте!

Есть список вида

```
l = [(2, 3), (4, 3), (2, 1), (5, 8), (5, 2), (4, 4)]
```

Как из него можно получить словарь

```
d = {2: 4, 4: 7, 5: 10}
```

т.е. ключ - первый элемент, а значение - сумма вторых.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например, через `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

for k, v in [(2, 3), (4, 3), (2, 1), (5, 8), (5, 2), (4, 4)]:
    d[k] += v

print(d)  # {2: 4, 4: 7, 5: 10}
```

---

Если через обычный словарь:

```
d = dict()

for k, v in [(2, 3), (4, 3), (2, 1), (5, 8), (5, 2), (4, 4)]:
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = 0

    d[k] += v

print(d)  # {2: 4, 4: 7, 5: 10}
```

Answer (score 3):

Еще есть способ с использованием `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for k, v in [(2, 3), (4, 3), (2, 1), (5, 8), (5, 2), (4, 4)]:
    c[k] += v
d = dict(c)
```